# Printing labels in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to loop and plot file information

```
-1 1 0.732313
-1 2 1.33585
-1 4 1.05306
-1 8 1.56261
-1 16 1.90336
-1 32 1.71105
-1 64 1.8319
```

which is loaded to `mat0`
This is what I have so far:

```
mat0 = genfromtxt("mydata")
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
mybel =-1
count =0
while (count < 60):
    i=count
    j= i+6                                      
    plt.plot(mat0[i:j,1], mat0[i:j,2],label="Size %s"%mybel)
    count = count + 7
    mybel = mybel +1

plt.show()
```

The problem is that I do not get labels printed at all. I do not get any error either. What am I missing?

Comment: `%s` is for strings. Are you sure you get no error?

Comment: @cricket_007 Aye, no errors (?) but it is not printing anything either

Comment: What is `mat0`? Can you make a [mcve] please?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, apologies. I'll update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `legend` object. You do this by calling `plt.legend()`.

```
mat0 = genfromtxt("mydata")
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
mybel =-1
count =0
while (count < 60):
    i=count
    j= i+6                                      
    plt.plot(mat0[i:j,1], mat0[i:j,2],label="Size %s"%mybel)
    count = count + 7
    mybel = mybel +1
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```